# Big O complexity C

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

```
a = 0;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   for(j = pow(n, 1/(i*i)); j>=1; j/=2) {
   a += f(i);
   }
}
```

Need Big O for this section of code. `f(i)` runs at constant time, n>>1.

I'm 100% sure answer is O(n) because limit when x is approaching to infinity of 1/x^2 is 0 so even for large number `i` I have `j=pow(n,0)=1` so condition `j>=1` in every step (`i` doesn't matter) assures that `f(i)` will be run at least once.

Official answer is O(logn) but I think it would be true if we have `j>1`, and if `j` is an integer.

I just need confirmation.

Comment: Welcome on SO. It doesn't seem to me that your question has anything to do with the programming language in which this is formulated, so I'll remove the C tag. Generally we aren't here to solve your assignments for you. You'd have to show a little bit more effort to be sure to interest somebody, here. Then, think of the outer loop, it will run exactly `n` times, so the complexity can't be less than `O(n)`. So what you are reporting about the "official" answer can't hold.  So probably you didn't even transcribe your assigment properly.

Comment: Where did you see that it's `O(log(n))`? The inner loop has `log(n)` iterations for `i = 1`, but for every other `i` it has 1 iteration only. The outer loop runs `n` times, so overall complexity is never going to be better than `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you both. I put an effort (solved it mathematically on my exam), just asked here for confirmation. This is a copy from my exam (they put it online) and I wrote O(n) in my exam, but offical answer on our site is O(logn) so that means they're wrong. Once again, thank you both.

Comment: Indeed, if that's exactly the code they show, I believe there has been a mistake in the solution. It's clearly `O(n)`.